# How to modify a class inside a module inside a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to get the twitter timeline of a specific user, but the way the Twitter gem works, it is sorting the tweets on the opposite order I need (newest to oldest). The twitter gem groups the timeline tweets of a user in an Array, but if i try to use sort, or invert it doesnt work.

I believe this is because the class of each tweet (Hashie::Mash) does not implement a < = > method or the comparable module. Does this make sense?

So I am trying to implement it but I am not sure how. How can I add new stuff to the Mash class?
If I understood correctly, each tweet's class is Mash, inside of the Hashie module, inside the Twitter module/gem?

I am trying to modify that class with this code:

```
  module Twitter
   module Hashie
    class Mash
      def testmethod
       puts 'hello world'
      end
    end
   end
  end
```

But it is not working...(although I am not getting any errors). Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Feel free to edit the title if the question is not the right one

Answer (score 2):

The `Hashie::Mash` class is part of the `hashie` gem and (like the name suggests) is not part of the `Twitter` namespace. If you want to extend it, use

```
module Hashie
  class Mash < Hash
     ...
  end
end
```

... or even simpler:

```
class Hashie::Mash < Hashie::Hash
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you Koractor. So the gem is called Hashie? I figured that the gem´s name was Twitter (because I installed it and included it with that name). Is twitter just the name of the file or what?

Comment: No, the gem you're working with is called `twitter` and its namespace is `Twitter`.  But it is depending on another gem called `hashie` which namespace is `Hashie`. That's probably the cause of confusion. :)

Comment: I cant get any of these to work: if I use the first method, I get a " superclass mismatch for class Mash" error. If I use the second, I get "uninitialized constant Object::Hashie". Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my examples so the superclass is specified. This should fix the first problem. The second example needs to know the `Hashie` namespace (because it will access it using `::`). You'll probably be sure to have already required your gems (`twitter` or specifically `hashie`) when using the second syntax.

Comment: SO why is this? When there is inheritance on the class you are tryyng to extend, you have to specify the superclass? I dont really get it. Thank you

Comment: The problem here is probably that your extension code was loaded before the `hashie` gem was. That way, Ruby sees that `hashie` wants to extend the class you just defined, but `hashie` uses a superclass for that class which would be illegal (you can't redefine a superclass). It's a matter of execution sequence.

Comment: Oh, I thought I understood...but it still doesnt work, I get the same errors. Sorry for bothering you so much Koractor...

Comment: Well, then the best would probably be to `require 'hashie'` right in front of your extension.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved by requiring 'hashie' inside the Twitter module.

```
module Twitter
  require "hashie"
end
```

That works for me.